# Runtime exception implementation

Tags: exception, runtime

I am trying to understand one concept regarding runtime exceptions, specifically catchable exceptions such as NullReferenceException in C#, at a high-level.

I think of runtime exceptions as errors that occur, during runtime, that the program does not know how to handle. In such cases, the memory is dumped and the program crashes.

In the case of a NullReferenceException (just an example for a catchable exception), this does not occur. The invalid state is observed, caught, and the program can continue. How can this be? Doesn't catching an exception imply the program is aware an exception occurred, but if an exception occurred, how is the program able to continue? Is an exception not a situation in which the program can't, or does not know how to, continue?

Is the runtime constantly 'looking ahead' and checking the next line before running, therefore 'catching' the exception just before it occurs?

Answer (score 0):

That is a really good question, there are a lot of webpages and tutorials telling you how to catch and handle exceptions, but what exactly is an exception. Once you try to program micro controllers without an OS, you will miss exception handling.

Please refer to the following link as starting point for your investigation:
http://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_crash_course_depths_of_win32_seh.htm

Beware that this article is pretty old and probably not the whole truth about exceptions, especially when looking at Managed Exceptions, but I hope you find it useful.